# How to specify the directory as classpath in order to read a file in it using classloader while running java application?

Tags: java, classpath

Let's say there is a file `abc.txt` present in directory `dir`. I am trying to run a java application using following command
`java -cp dir;myjar.jar com.example.Main`

And in Main class, I am trying to access this file like this `getClass().getResource("/abc.txt")`. But this is returning null. I am not sure what's wrong here. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You may use `getResource("/abc.txt")` to get a resource which is at the top level of your class path. If you omit the `/` then the resource is searched for in a path relative to your class. See the javadoc for getResource() at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

Comment: I got it but, dir is not the current directory from where I am running my application. It's parent directory of dir. It's not working with it.

Comment: @HarshYadav Let's say `dir` is `C:\foo` and your class is `com.example.Test`. If you specify `"abc.txt"`, it will look for `C:/foo/com/example/abc.txt`. If you specify `"/abc.txt"`, it will look for `C:/foo/abc.txt`. Current directory is not checked, at all.

Comment: @Andreas But later is not working. Let's I am in directory `c:\example` which contains `myjar.jar` and directory `dir` which in turn contains file `abc`.

Comment: @HarshYadav Still should work, so something you haven't told us is wrong. Please provide [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. show your directory structure, which files are where, what you full class name is, etc.

Comment: @Andreas It worked as you said I have made some mistake in that.

Answer (score 2):

Since the file is in the root of the classpath directory, you need to use `"/abc.txt"`, otherwise it's looking in the package folder for the class in question.

Just like the javadoc of [`getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) says:

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> - If the `name` begins with a `'/'` (`'\u002f'`), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the `name` following the `'/'`.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>
>   ```
>    modified_package_name/name
>   ```
>
>   Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with `'/'` substituted for `'.'` (`'\u002e'`).